# Why does the simple_format helper seem to ignore double new lines in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a micropost feature and was testing the way it formats text that has been posted when displaying back to the user.

**I pasted the following text like this**:

[image]

**and this was displayed back to me:**

[image]

I'm using "simple_format h(content)". When I remove the helper the text is displayed with out a new line from the word "In". It displays as one big paragraph so I assume the helper is working but for some reason my double new lines are being ignored.

Any idea what is going on? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to chrome developer tools as per usual. I realised that each text separated by 2 new lines were wrapped with p tags so I just added a bottom margin of 5px using css to p. Works perfectly.

Comment: Ah yea. If it comes out in two paragraphs, that's really the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

By seeing it back, do you mean inside a textarea, or on the page? If it's on the page, all whitespace is compressed to one space each. If it's the latter, simply use the css rule:

```
white-space:pre;
```

On the proper selector.

However, if it is in a textarea (which preserves whitespace by default), there must be something stripping the extra space when you save it into the database. You might want to debug down your stack in the model & controller, to see where this might be happening. I have to admit i haven't used the the simple_format method.

Comment: It's on the page. In the text area it displays fine. I tried adding white-space pre to the p tag css and it seems to make the text stretch wide out of the box it's displayed in causing a horizontal scroll bar to appear